# Как инициализировать статические поля до первого вызова их геттеров?

Tags: java

Мне нужен доступ к статическим полям класса, которые должны быть инициалированы до вызова их геттера. Например, у класса есть поле `private static Map<String, Integer> countryAndId`. В другом классе, мне нужно получить значение этого поля: `Map<String, Integer> countryAndId = Countries.getCountryAndId();`
Как мне сделать, чтобы это поле (и другие) инициализировались на старте программы автоматически и я мог просто получать его?
Надеюсь я правильно и доступно объяснил

---

Всё, решил несколькими строками вот так:

```
static  {
    fillCountryAndId();
}
```

в методе fillCountryAndId() реализовал весь код инициализации.

Но есть одно "НО!": эта инициализация происходит каждый раз как я вызываю геттер. А как инициализировать только один раз? Что-то типа синглтона, один раз сделал и пользуешься пока живет программа? Может сделать это в виде того же синглтона, а поля сделать нестатическими? Это вроде решает проблему?

P.S. Сделал класс синглтоном. Работает как надо, при этом нужно создавать объект синглтона, а не вызывать статические методы класса, как я планировал изначально.

Comment: В блоке static{} укажите начальные значения или в конструкторе.

Comment: Напишите свое решение в виде ответа.

Comment: Как вы установили, что `эта инициализация происходит каждый раз как я вызываю геттер`? Такого быть не может. Приведите пожалуйста программу, которая подтверждает ваши слова.

Answer (score 2):

Самое правильное было бы написать

```
private static Map<String, Integer> countryAndId=makeCountryAndId();
```

То, как вы написали

```
static  {
    fillCountryAndId();
}
```

тоже годится. В обоих случаях инициализация производится только один раз.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Для уточнений используйте комментарии под вопросом, а не ответы.

Comment: @pavloff Очень даже является. Вопрос был - `Как мне сделать, чтобы это поле (и другие) инициализировались на старте программы автоматически`, мой ответ - написать определение переменной с инициализацией, либо использовать static блок.

Comment: @rfq, если вы написали **ответ**, то логично будет **комментарий**, содержащийся в вашем сообщении, оттуда убрать. и добавить его (при необходимости) именно как комментарий в соответствующем месте.

Comment: В ответах не может быть никаких просьб о приведении программ и подтверждениях. Этому место в комментарии. Здесь не форум с дискускссиями "Чем докажешь ...", а Q&A, ответ - это решение проблемы в вопросе, а не ее обсуждение.